# Should I, and could I, replace bluez?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a question about bluez. I am wondering if there are any alternatives to bluez bluetooth support that I can use. The reason I am asking, is because I have a ralink 3290 bluetooth adapter, which is currently not being recognized. I know that the blue device works, because it works fine in windows. I have followed quite a few tutorials to make it work to no avail.

When I compiled the driver, I managed to get it recognized, but would not pair. The adapter I am using is built-in, not sure if it makes a difference.  My questions are as follows:

- Are there any alternatives to bluez, that might be able to recognize the bluetooth adapter?  (is this even the right question to ask?)
- If so, can you name a few (or even one)?
- Would there be any consequences to removing bluez, like the desktop no longer being available?

Any and all assistance that anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Removing Bluez will not fix the problem as the bluetooth device might never work in Linux as Ralink will not help.  I would buy a micro USB bluetooth like the IOGear GBU521

Comment: I thank you for the feedback.  I was wondering that myself, so it would seem easier to buy a new bluetooth adapter.  It really is a shame to waste a perfectly good bluetooth adapter.  I guess I will have to make sure to buy my next computer, with a built-in bluetooth adapter, not made by Ralink in the future.  I will give up on this issue then.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Bluez will result in a great deal of packages being removed, you can check that with synaptic or just read the confirmation message what will be removed. I would advise against this as it might be hard trying to reinstall needed packages for other bluetooth stacks (I haven't heard of any other than Bluez though)

As for recognizing the bluetooth adapter; you can check that with `hciconfig`. It will show you your Bluetooth Device. Using the `-h`  parameter also shows a list of possible options to help you troubleshoot why it is not being recognized, such as the pairing mode.  You could also try to `-reset` it. What are you trying to pair, by the way? The BT adapter with the PC? If so; that isn't necessary and quite impossible if I recall correctly.

I'm not sure what you mean with "When I compiled the driver I managed to get it recognized" Did you use any tools and what do you mean by recognized? What driver did you compile; Bluez?

Versions 4.x of Bluez are still distributed with Ubuntu distro's whereas the unstable branches of Debian have almost up-to-date 5.x releases of Bluez. You could try running a Debian version that has the 5.x releases of Bluez in it and see if you are able to pair or do anything. You can check your version of Bluez with `bluetoothd -v`.

Switching from 4.x to 5.x helped me a lot and fixed a lot of errors regarding my Bluetooth workflow.